# TYPO3: use fluid's date view helper inline as argument for translate view helper

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I am currently developing some extensions to use within TYPO3 6.

In one view I have database records with date fields. I can output the date values with the following:

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y H:i:s">{record.validend}</f:format.date>
```

However, I need a translated message, so I would like to use the translate view helper and put the formatted date in the *arguments* attribute. Without succes so far.

I tried:

```
<f:translate key="{msg_id}" arguments="{0: code, 1: {f:format.date(date: record.validend, format: 'd.m.Y H:i:s')}}" htmlEscape="0" />
```

…and…

```
<f:translate key="{msg_id}" arguments="{0: code, 1: {record.validend -> f:format.date(format: 'd.m.Y H:i:s')}}" htmlEscape="0" />
```

…following this guide: http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Fluid_Inline_Notation

However, there seems to be some syntax error in my notation forcing fluid to interpret the whole thing as a string, resulting in an error, cause the arguments attribut is expected to be an array.

Could anyone tell me if what I want is possible, and what syntax I need?

best regards

Christian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes of format with backslashes.

The solution is:

```
<f:translate key="{msg_id}" arguments="{0: code, 1: '{f:format.date(date: record.validend, format: \'d.m.Y H:i:s\')}'}" htmlEscape="false" />
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. I didn't set the inline view helper in single Quotes and thus didn't think of having to escape the quotes inside.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use format.date as variable is:

```
{f:format.date(format : 'd-m-Y H:i:s', date : '@1368093280')}
```

I tested your request and it seems that it isnt possible to call a ViewHelper inside the argument `arguments` of a ViewHelper.

So you should try something else like a custom ViewHelper or format your date in the controller so you have a variable that contains the formatted date:

```
{f:translate(key : msg.id, arguments : {0 : msg.date})}
```